# Difference in the two ways of checking equality i==0 vs 0==i in C++

Tags: c++

I am going through a huge code-base in C++. The author has used `0==i` syntax for checking equality. I have been coding in C++ for quite some years now; I have always used `i==0` syntax.

Does the former have any advantages over the latter? Or is it just personal preference?

Comment: The latter has the huge (!) advantage that a typo like `0 = i` is a compiler error.

Comment: The former produces a compiler-error when you forgot the second equal-sign. `0 = i` doesn't compile, `i = 0` does.

Comment: Two answers in the comments section. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The former has the advantage that it prevents the programmer from accidentally leaving out an equals sign.

```
if (i = 0)
```

The above is legal, and sets `i` to zero, and is false (since zero is considered false).

```
if (0 = i)
```

The above is illegal in all contexts.

Today, most compilers will warn about `if (i = 0)`, but it is not a requirement, and they didn't always do so.

Answer (score 13):

`0==i` is called a "yoda conditional". It is most certainly a personal preference, but it does have an advantage.

It was used in the dark ages by mystical knights of the realm who lacked the modern technology to tell them when they'd written `0=i` by mistake.

A compiler will reject an accidental `0=i`, but it'll accept an accidental `i=0`.

This convention was phased out after the war of 1672. Contemporary shamans try to write code that makes sense to other shamans (also pixies, elves and humans), and instead use compilers written in this millennium (also, their *eyes*) to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: I appreciate your way of explaining things, but I would disagree that contemporary compilers have got rid of this. I did this typo last year, and it was not easy to debug this. I don't remember the exact compiler version, but it should not be that old. :D

Comment: Bull! Great, great, great Aunt Ada used it as recently as the 1850s!

Comment: @SonuMishra sometimes you have to turn the warning levels up to get it, but it's usually there.

Comment: @SonuMishra: That's where _eyes_ come in! I see why people use this, but I believe that it lulls people into a false sense of security, AND I believe that if you're not paying enough attention to spot a `=` vs `==`, then what else are you missing? Pay more attention. Simply read your code. :) And get your colleagues to code review. **tl;dr If you're missing this, you're almost certainly missing other things that yoda conditionals do _not_ solve for you. Fix that by fixing yourself**

Comment: :) I can't help but point out that testing the code can help too.

Answer (score 3):

For simple integer, as others explained, `0 == i` minimizes risk of making a typo.

However, if you have an overloaded `operator==`, then `0 == i` might be an error:

```
class X
{
public:
    X(int x) : _x(x) {};
    bool operator==(int y) { return _x == y; }
private:
    int _x;
};

....

X x(0);
if (x == 0) // OK
    ;
if (0 == x) // error
    ;
```